# No such column 'ContactEmail' on case

Tags: apex

```
Case recordCase = [ SELECT ID, Description,SuppliedEmail,
                    ContactId,AccountId, ContactEmail
                    FROM Case 
                    WHERE Id = '50028000000rI2K'
                  ];
system.debug('recordCase:-\n' + recordCase);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just a little mistake, you need to apply . in between contact and email...

so query is like :

```
Case recordCase = [ SELECT ID, Description,SuppliedEmail,
                    ContactId,AccountId, Contact.Email
                    FROM Case 
                    WHERE Id = '50028000000rI2K'
                  ];
system.debug('recordCase:-\n' + recordCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try the Following Query.

```
Case recordCase = [ SELECT ID, Description,SuppliedEmail, ContactId,AccountId,
Contact.Email FROM Case WHERE Id = '50028000000rI2K' ]; 
system.debug('recordCase:-\n' + recordCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation located [HERE (H&T)](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cases_fields.htm):

> **Contact Email** Email address of a case’s contact. The address is added
>   when you add a contact to a case. This field is read only.

**HOWEVER**

The SOAP API Developer Guide [HERE (SOAP API)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_case.htm) does not list this as a field

Regardless, it is as simple as using `Contact.Email` in your query. Sometimes artifacts are left over from design choices that cannot be undone yet are made no longer available.

Yet, the choice to have it may have been to simply allow for use in Email alerts, email to case, etc as the email field needs to be on the object to work properly

So, while you can still see it in the UI, it is not available for use in a query at this point

Comment: alternate explanation - the H&T list of fields includes some 'pseudo' or 'convenience' fields that SFDC makes available to the point-and-click UI so that list views, workflow rules, email templates are more useful. When using SOQL, one must, of course, use the real API fields that won't, by definition, include these 'convenience' fields

Comment: @crop1645 - thanks for that. I had that in lumped into the previous paragraph and not in as much detail

Comment: it was your sentence "it was removed from the API at some point" that caught my eye.

Comment: @crop1645 - Yea, I was just giving possibilities as I really did not know the exact reason. Will remove that part

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this was something that was recently removed. I had a query referencing one of the contact fields that recently stopped working when I updated the API version. A long term fix would be to change to contact.email, but changing the API version on the class to 37 or lower should also fix the issue.

Comment: Please see my 'convenience fields' comment under Eric's answer. The fields you enumerate in the screen shot are a `superset` of real, SOQL-queryable fields

Comment: They may be convenience fields, but that doesn't explain to me why they would suddenly stop working at a certain API version and yet remain in the documentation. Previously, it worked as the documentation implied that it would and it no longer does. That is *removing* functionality, it's not something like URL hacks where we always knew it could be broken.